# 6 is a unique number $n$ such that $n-LD(n)^2 = 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $LD(n)$ be the lowest divisor of $n$ larger than $1$. Let's find all numbers $n$ such that $n-LD(n)^2 = 2$. If $n$ is even then $LD(n) = 2$ and $LD(n)^2 = 4$. Plugging in we get $n-4=2$, so $n=6$. That is one solution. But is it unique? I think it is. Here is my reasoning.

I have shown that the only even solution is $6$. In trying to find further solutions we may disregard all numbers divisible by $2$. What about numbers divisible by $3$? Numbers divisible by $3$ either are or are not divisible by $2$. If they are divisible by $2$ we may safely ignore them. If they are not divisible by $2$ then $LD(n) = 3$ and $n-9=2$ and so $n=11$. Since $11$ is not divisible by $3$ we see we may safely disregard all number divisible by $3$.

Suppose we have shown that we can disregard all numbers divisible by numbers smaller than $2k+1$ (but greater than 1). Consider numbers that are divisible by $2k+1$. If they are divisible by a number smaller than itself we can disregard them. If not $LD(2k+1)= 2k+1$ and $n-(4k^2+4k+1)= 2$ and $n = 4k^2+4k+3$. This number is never divisible by $2k+1$. Therefore, we may safely ignore all numbers divisible by $2k+1$.

Since we know that we can ignore all numbers divisible by numbers smaller than $3$, we can ignore all number divisible by $3$, we can ignore all the numbers divisible by $4$ (since we can ignore all even numbers) and we can ignore all numbers divisible by $5$ and so on. The dominoes start falling.

Is this argument valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there's a much better way of doing this.  Note that $LD(n)$ has to be prime since if it is not prime there will be at least two prime divisors $p,q<LD(n)$. Since $LD(n)|n$, let $k$ such that $LD(n)k=n$.  Then we are looking for $LD(n)(k-LD(n))=2$.  If $LD(n)|2$ and $LD(n)$ must be prime, then $LD(n)=2$.  $n-2^2=2\Longrightarrow n=6$.

Comment: Do we know that k-LD(n) cannot be even?

Comment: Yes.  Since $LD(n)(k-LD(n))=2$ and $LD(n)=2$, $k-LD(n)=1$

Comment: Dont we need to know that k-LD(n) cannot be even to conclude that LD(n) = 2 ?

Comment: No.  By your supposition, $LD(n)>1$.  All positive integer divisors of $2$ are $\{1,2\}$, so $LD(n)$ can only be $2$.  Alternatively, you can use my reasoning and select the only prime divisor of $2$, which is $2$.

Comment: How do you know that LD(n) divides 2?

Comment: $LD(n)(k-LD(n))=2$

Comment: From this I would conclude that either LD(n) or k-LD(n) have to be even

Comment: But they are both natural numbers so the only possibilites are 2*1 and 1*2, and we can eliminate 1*2 since LD(n) > 1, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11774/discussion-between-tim-ratigan-and-adam)

Answer (score 3):

The argument appears valid, even though it is not very well expressed. I would replace a phrase like "suppose we can disregard all numbers [such and such]", for which it is not clear what this means exactly (since it does not say which fact allows is to disregard those numbers), by "suppose we have shown [some explicit property]".

However, above all you can simplify the reasoning to the following. Let $p=LD(n)$ (it is a prime number, but this is not actually used). Then $p$ divides both $p^2$ and $n$ (the latter by definition of $LD(n)$). Then it also divides $n-p^2=2$, and this leaves $p=2$ as only possibility.